# How to show/hide extra section in antd card with mouse over?

Tags: reactjs, antd, mouseover, card

I am using `antd` cards in my `react` project.
I want to show and hide `extra` content in my card with mouse hover on the card.

this is my card:

```
<Card
    title="My Card Title"
    extra={<Button type="link"> Download </Button>}
>
some content...
</Card>
```

I want to show `Download button` just when the mouse hover the card.
How can I control the visibility of `extra` section in `antd card` with mouseover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, You need an `state` for show/hide event:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
```

Second, you should make an mouse event function:

```
 const mouseHover = () => setShow(prev => !prev)
```

And finally add this logic into your card with events like this:

```
<Card
    title="My Card Title"
    extra={show ? <Button type="link"> Download </Button> : null}
    onMouseEnter={mouseHover}
    onMouseLeave={mouseHover}
>
some content...
</Card>
```